# Sending the data of a text box to an email id on the button click in android

Tags: android, email

I am having an android form and one of the field is Email ID.I want take that email id and send some data on that email id on the click of a button on the same activity.
What are the possible ways by which we can send the data.

Comment: Yes I want to send the email that is written in the EditBox on the click of a button.

Comment: you can refer Dheeresh Singh 's answer if you any doubt in that let me know

Comment: In that example,data has been send to a particular email ID .But i want to send the data(Of my own) to the email ID that the user enter in the EditText.

Comment: there are two examples which one you have tried using sending mail intent or using javamail api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 ways

1- using native email app 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
it will open the screen with data pre-filled in form. You have to send data in intent.

2- Send without native app

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

Answer (score 2):

it's very easy to send an Email with data taken from an `EditText`

```
String mail = "this is the Email message body";
i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); // start the activity for sending an email
i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email"); //set the mime type for the Email
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "FW: " + "subject");
String[] to = {editText.getText().toString()};
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);

i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(mail));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "EMAIL"));
```